How do I prove these left and right Jacobian properties of SO(3)?
I've been reading Sola, J., Quaternion Kinematics for the Error-State Kalman Filter, 2017. Sola provides three properties for the right Jacobian of SO(3) for any $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ and small $\delta \boldsymbol{\theta}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Exp} (\boldsymbol{\theta} + \delta \boldsymbol{\theta}) &\approx \text{Exp}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \text{Exp}(\mathbf{J}_r(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \delta \boldsymbol{\theta}) \\
\text{Exp}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \text{Exp}(\delta \boldsymbol{\theta}) &\approx \text{Exp}(\boldsymbol{\theta} + \mathbf{J}^{-1}_r (\boldsymbol{\theta}) \delta \boldsymbol{\theta}) \\
\text{Log}(\text{Exp}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \text{Exp}(\delta \boldsymbol{\theta})) &\approx \boldsymbol{\theta} + \mathbf{J}^{-1}_r (\boldsymbol{\theta}) \delta \boldsymbol{\theta},
\end{align}
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\theta}, \delta \boldsymbol{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ are the rotation vectors such that skew symmetric form $\left[ \boldsymbol{\theta} \right]_\times \in \mathfrak{so}(3)$. $Exp(\cdot)$ is the exponential mapping $\mathfrak{so}(3) \rightarrow SO(3)$, i.e, $\exp(\left[ \boldsymbol{\theta} \right]_\times) = \mathbf{R}$. Similarly, $Log(\cdot)$ is the inverse logarithm mapping. The right Jacobian is defined as:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{J}_r(\boldsymbol{\theta}) &= \mathbf{I} - \frac{1 - \cos||\boldsymbol{\theta}||}{||\boldsymbol{\theta}||^2} \left[ \boldsymbol{\theta} \right]_\times + \frac{||\boldsymbol{\theta}|| - \sin||\boldsymbol{\theta}||}{||\boldsymbol{\theta}||^2}\left[ \boldsymbol{\theta} \right]^2_\times
\end{align}
$$
The second identity can be derived using Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula per Barfoot, State Estimation for Robotics, 2024 and the third identity can be directly obtained from the second identity. However, I can't seem to derive the first property. Barfoot also seems to be using the same property in p303, eq.8109a and eq.8109b for the left Jacobian.
How do I derive the first property:
$$
\text{Exp} (\boldsymbol{\theta} + \delta \boldsymbol{\theta}) \approx \text{Exp}(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \text{Exp}(\mathbf{J}_r(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \delta \boldsymbol{\theta})
$$
Any pointers is much appreciated!

Refrain from adding links, this forces viewers to click in the link to understand your question. Summarize if required.

Please, add all definitions indispensable in understanding the problem into the problem statement. Those are pretty long documents. For instance, what is $\mathbf{\theta}$? The term "right Jacobian" is also unfamiliar to me.

Updated with definitions of the variables and operators.
I don't think the links are necessary for the question.

The main motivation for the right-jacobian is being the linear transformation that makes the following expression true:
$$
\text{Exp}(\mathbf{u} + \delta \mathbf{u}) \approx \text{Exp}(\mathbf{u}) \oplus  \mathcal{J}_r(\mathbf{u}) \delta \mathbf{u}, \delta \mathbf{u} \in  \mathcal{T}_{\text{Exp}(\mathbf{u})}.
$$
This leads to the following definition based on limits:
$$
\mathcal{J}_{r} := \lim_{\|\mathbf{h}\| \to 0 } \left(\frac{\text{Exp}(\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{h}) \ominus \text{Exp}(\mathbf{u})}{\| \mathbf{h} \|}\right)
$$
Moreover, you can find an approximation for it with the following code snippet:
def getRightJacobian(v):
    eps = 1e-7
    h = eps*torch.eye(3,3, dtype=torch.double )
    N = v.size(0)
    v = v.double()
    res = torch.zeros(N,3,3, dtype=torch.double)
    X = t.so3.so3_exp_map(v, eps = 1e-16)
    for j in range(3):
        h_i  = h[j,:]
        Y = t.so3.so3_exp_map(v + h_i, eps = 1e-16)
        num = X.inverse() * Y
        log = t.so3.so3_log_map(num,eps = 1e-16)    
        res[:,:,j] = log/eps
    return res

